# create a "save for offline reading" button

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, app-offline.htm

So I am exploring different ways to create HTML5 mobile apps. Trying to avoid mobile frameworks and complex APIs such as Sencha and Titanium. One idea I have is make use of the "save for offline reading" feature. Is it possible to create a button the user can click on that would accomplish this?

assuming this is possible:
-does this feature enabled with JavaScript?
-is it possible to connect to db online?

The entire point is to get a similar effect as if you had an `.html` file on your comp that wanted open in a browser. It would be offline but could run JavaScript, load external files. How could I go about achieving this on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to save anything for offline is to use the app cache. Once the app cache is enabled on the html page you can have other files load but it's the manifest file that comes from the server that decides what is cached and what is not.

I wrote a little library that copies any script and images from the page and saves it to localstoage. You still need to enable the app cache but it let's you dynamically pick what to save offline. The local storage has a limit of 5 MB so it's not much if you have images to save. (https://github.com/puppybits/Offline.js)

```
<html manifest="appcache.manifest">
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="offline.js">
  <script>
  var offline = new Offline(); // options: {document: myDocFragment, useThreads: false}
  if (navigator.onLine)
  {
    offline.prime()
  }
  else
  {
    offline.activate()
  }
  </script>
</html>
```